# SSH from Ubuntu to Windows: different results over Wi-Fi and Ethernet

Tags: linux, windows-10, networking, ssh, ethernet

## Problem Statement

I'm gonna give a lot of details here, just in case any of them are relevant.

I need to ssh through ethernet from a linux machine (Thinkpad X1 Extreme running Pop!_OS 18.04) into a windows one (Microsoft Surface laptop 3 13'' running windows 10 enterprise). Neither machine actually has an ethernet port, so I've got the Thinkpad hooked up to [a usb-to-ethernet hub](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0178HOTOU) and the surface to a [Surface Dock](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0163HP38W). The hub and the dock are hooked up with an Insignia Cat-5e  network cable (I can't see anything about crossover on it, if that's relevant)

## The Setup

I can already ssh from the thinkpad to the surface just fine over my home's wifi network: I've already set up OpenSSH server and added "allow connection" rules in Windows firewall, so that

```
# 10.0.0.211 is windows machine's ip address
ssh user@10.0.0.211
ssh user@10.0.0.211 -p 2222
```

both work flawlessly. (I've set up a Linux subsystem for windows ssh server on port 2222 using the instructions [here](https://jeetblogs.org/post/sshing-into-a-windows-wsl-linux-subsystem/); if I had my way I wouldn't be using windows at all).

You can see my Linux subsystem's `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` file [here](https://gist.github.com/anlsh-msft/16466a77d1466de669c6a2e3c28a75d9)

However due to some latency issues, the wi-fi isn't good enough which brings me to trying to use ethernet.

Anyways, when both machines are plugged into their hubs and the hubs connected via ethernet, both machines definitely realize that *something* is going on.

From Ubuntu, I can see the relevant connection (usb ethernet)[image].

Per some other resource I was googling, I went into the Ipv4 tab of the settings to set it as link-local[image].

After application, the connection's details look this this [image]

An `ifconfig` confirms the information from the GUI, showing

```
enx00e04c7145d1: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 169.254.23.78  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 169.254.255.255
        inet6 fe80::497c:4c41:876d:eae2  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 00:e0:4c:71:45:d1  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 178  bytes 15857 (15.8 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 59  bytes 7820 (7.8 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

(There are various other connections listed ofc: this is the one that disappears when the ethernet is unplugged).

For what it's worth, Windows also recognizes the connection as an "unidentified network"
[image]

Clicking on that network brings shows me the following settings/info

[image]

## Problematic behavior

On my linux machine, I would expect to be able to simply replace `10.0.0.211` with `169.254.23.78` in my `ssh` commands and have everything "just work." However, things are never so simple.

When I `ssh user@169.254.23.78` I'm given the password prompt, but am rejected even with the same username/password combo which works over the wi-fi ip

```
me@pop-os ~ % ssh user@169.254.23.78
user@169.254.23.78's password: <password>
Permission denied, please try again.
user@169.254.23.78's password: <password>
Permission denied, please try again.
user@169.254.23.78's password: <password>
user@169.254.23.78: Permission denied (publickey,password).
```

Trying to ssh over port `2222` also fails, but for a totally different(?) reason

```
user@pop-os ~ % ssh user@169.254.23.78 -p 2222
ssh: connect to host 169.254.23.78 port 2222: Connection refused
```

How can I get this setup to work?

Comment: By the fact that you have not mentioned connecting your hub/switch to your router, I will assume that you just have two computers connected together with a hub/switch and no wired router at all. Because there is no router/gateway to assign private IPs on your wired network, your computers will assign themselves an autoconfiguration IP (the 169 IP address). This is not meant to actually be used. Manually assign your wired adapters IP addresses on a subnet and then it should work. Also, gigabit ethernet doesn't actually need a hub/switch. You can plug the cable directly between the two PCs.

Comment: The computers *are* directly connected, just via respective adapters (calling my thinkpad's usb-to-ethernet thing a "hub" might have been misleading). Also, what do you mean assign them both "ip addresses on a subnet"? I'm assuming you mean the same subnet? Do the manually' assigned IPs have to be the same on both computers?

Comment: Really, any private IP network will do. IP addresses must always be different. For example, using the the 192.168.0.1/24 network: Assign one computer the 192.168.0.1 address and assign the other the 192.168.0.2 address (subnet mask 255.255.255.0). Then the computers should be accessible via the manually assigned addresses.

Comment: Worked like a charm, thank you! If you'd like to copy/paste your comments into an answer I can mark this question as answered

Comment: Sure, glad I was able to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When connecting computers together without using a DHCP server (router/gateway, or otherwise), you must manually assign each machine an IP address on a network of your choosing. If you have more than two machines you wish to connect to each other, you may use a hub/switch. Otherwise, connecting the two machines directly together using a normal ethernet cable (as long as both machines/network adapters support gigabit ethernet) will suffice.

As an example, let's use the 192.168.0.0/24 network. After the machines have been connected (either directly or with a hub/switch), assign each machine a separate IP address in the 192.168.0.1 - 192.168.0.254 range, with subnet mask 255.255.255.0. Since there is no internet/gateway on this network, you can leave the "Default Gateway" and "DNS Server" fields blank.

After you have manually assigned each machine an IP address, they should be able to communicate by using the addresses you manually assigned to them.